# How to colour certain picture parts in Android?

Tags: android, image, canvas, svg

I'm writing an app which allows the user to change the colour of countries on the world map by tapping on them. At the moment I'm struggling to find the apt way to store and display the map, allowing it to be partly coloured at the same time.

On of the solutions I had in mind was to use an SVG and a third-party library, but as far as I know none of them provides the necessary callback to modify the image once it's drawn.

I am merely at the beginning of understanding of what Canvas is, but even now it is clear to me that drawing such a complex object as a world map on Canvas is way too hard. It will probably take ages to load as well.

I have not implemented any of the mentioned things yet. I assume there is a better way that most developers use, so I'd like to find out what it is.

Comment: What map do you use? Is it GoogleMap?

Comment: Depending on if they are all initially different & each solid colors you could possibly just change a color like this: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/image-processing-pixel-color-replacement/

Possibly might be able to get away with acute changes to the colors.

Otherwise, I'm sure there's multiple ways to go with this, eg. mapping touches to bitmap location and change somehow or using 3rd party map that offers this, etc.

Comment: @RaymondLukanta it's a picture of a map

Comment: @CmosBattery the colours are all the same in the beginning and sadly the design of the app does not allow me to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than a year I have finally found a working solution.
[Google Map's Android API Utils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) provide a great means of applying various overlays to Google Map views and fragments as well as changing their individual components.

I went with a geojson layer upon the map and updated the fill colour of certain features.